# pop-up window for login UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, popup, social-networking

There is a problem, I do Sharing for social networks. I download sdk facebook and there is very nice pop-up window for login. This window is UIWebView respectively.
How i can make this for other social networks?

Tried to alter the code in the library for Twitter - does not work (yet little skill  )

Help me make this pop-up window for simple UIWebView.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iOS6, you can use Social framework.
Presentation is good.

[WWDC 2012 Session Videos “Integration With Facebook, Twitter and Sina Weibo”](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=306)